# Any open source tool for Soap Api automation testing?

Tags: java, testing, soap, automation, soapui

I am new to testing frameworks. I have to write automated tests for a dozen of SOAP api's. But I don't know any open source framework to use.

I have read about the soap UI's PRO(Paid) and open source(free) versions. But I only need open source tools. And SOAP UI open source has some limitations.

So could someone point me the ways I can create tests. And the Open source tools which could be used.

Comment: SoapUI is an excellent tool for testing APIs.  It's true that the free version has limitations versus the Pro (paid for) version, but it's still a very good tool.  Maybe be you could persuade your employer to pay for the license.  Please note, I'm merely a Soap UI user and not affiliated with SmartBear in any way.  Postman is another excellent and free tool that you can use for testing APIs.  Danny Dainton has created an excellent source of training material for Postman (https://github.com/DannyDainton/All-Things-Postman).

Comment: Another free tool I have used is JMeter, whilst this is geared more towards performance and load testing, you can still use it to test an API.

Comment: As for "How do I create tests", well that depends on the tool and the API you're looking at.  I suggest doing some research here.

Comment: I use the open source version of SOAP UI a lot as it's test cases and suites are great, simply click a button and it will regression test 60+ web service API calls in seconds while validating the results.  I have read (I believe) that even with the free version, the test cases can be run from the command line so that gets you closer to automation.  If you'd like I can look into that aspect and provide an answer that might help.

Comment: @ChrisAdams we are already using Jmeter for the performance testing. And are further looking into the prospects of leveraging this tool's functionalities. And thanks for the Postman's comment. It looks like a promising tool for hitting the API. I am doing some handson on this tool.

Answer (score 0):

If you like to work with javascript you can use this open source Soap API test automation tool https://www.npmjs.com/package/teppa
It is simple, easy to use tool. You can find description about this tool here https://blog.qakitchen.com/2019/02/soap-api-test-automation-using.html